# Stop a running command

Tags: powershell, abort, ctrl

VSC Powershell V5 on Windows 10.

I started `Get-ChildItem -Path hkcu:\ -Recurse` with the <kbd>F8</kbd> key.

Apart from:

- Pause
- Ctrl-Pause
- closing VSC.

How do I STOP this command ?

Answer (score 2):

ctrl+c in terminal, shift+f5 if debugging

Comment: Isn't F5 is the Debug Run Command ?
Ctrl+C Works.
Thanks